# ReSharper Error: Cannot convert instance argument type 'System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal

Tags: asp.net-identity, resharper, identityserver4, visual-studio-2017

In a .net core class project, I have implemented `IClaimsService` of `IdentityServer4.Services`. I have the following code in that class

```
protected virtual IEnumerable<Claim> GetStandardSubjectClaims(IPrincipal subject)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, subject.GetSubjectId()),
        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.AuthenticationTime, subject.GetAuthenticationTimeEpoch().ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer),
        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.IdentityProvider, subject.GetIdentityProvider()),
    };

    claims.AddRange(subject.GetAuthenticationMethods());

    return claims;
}
```

In the above code **subject** is marked with red curvy underline, and the error is as follows

> Cannot convert instance argument type
>   'System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal [System.Security.Principal,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]' to
>   'System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal [System.Private.CoreLib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]'

Only, ReSarper is showing this as an error, not sure what to do to fix this. And this error stops showing other warnings, after filtering ReSharper shows other warnings

Comment: Let me double check - VS can build the project and this does not stop your app from running? And if you disable R# it is not underlined as error?

Comment: From VS it is alright, no warning no errors. Only R# is marking this as an error.

Comment: I presume you've cleared the R# cache and done other obvious steps (like VS restart)?

Comment: Yeap, I've cleared the cache, update all the packages to latest stable, then remove the local appdata and .vs folder to restore the packages. suspend and start r#. Then tried different computers and everywhere it seems same

Comment: Could be a bug.  Raise it with JetBrains.

Comment: @MJK defo a bug. Raise it with jetbrains. R# is full of such small annoyances -(

Comment: Agree it's a bug, have added a comment on your R# bug report to add my support to that.

Comment: JetBrains [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-465177)